# Getting exact URL in Struts2

Tags: url, struts2

I want to get the URL accessed by the Struts2 web application. For instance, if user accesses `http://www.webpage.com` or `https://www.webpage.com`, I need the protocol; http or https. I tried implementing the action with ServletRequestAware and using request.isSecure() or request.getScheme(). However, I am getting false and 'http' even if I access 'https://..' link.

Is there any way to get the protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it from the header:

```
System.out.println(request.getHeader("referer"));
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> https://www.webpage.com

Comment: I am getting null as output.

Comment: Then something is really wrong. Please post the way you get Request object.

Comment: Well. The action class implements ServletRequestAware. I have a private HttpServletRequest variable which gets set.

Comment: Does the Action extends ActionSupport too ?

Comment: Yes. It extends ActionSupport.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Can we change the referer from request to response? I mean request came in as https but response must be http. As after login we may not like to get encrypted data, so if login is successful load remaining pages in http.......... Struts-2-SSL plugin does not do it reverse so finding work-arounds.

Comment: You should open a question about this, that is a completely different matter; btw, if you are asking how to login in HTTPS, and after login browse on an HTTP web application, you can use some security system for that. For example, with Shibboleth (a popular Single Sign On system) we have a lot of HTTP locations secured under an HTTPS login page, with certificate, badge or username/password. But open a question to receive more detailed answers from experts on this argument ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to try one more thing.
Implement Action with ServletRequestAware and use

```
request.getProtocol();
```

Else you can use the following code in your action class:

```
HttpServletRequest request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String protocol=request.getProtocol();
    System.out.println("Protocol Used::"+protocol);
```

Comment: I am getting "Protocol Used::HTTP/1.1" as output

Comment: So you are actually getting what you wanted right?,the protocol.

Comment: Well.. Actually I need to check if it is accessed using http or https

Comment: So is it that you want to check whether your application is being accessed using htttp or https?Am i right?

Comment: Then dude... You have a problem, your application can be accessed using http only because... unless you have added SSL to your application It can never be accessed using https. And once you have added SSL, even if someone types http+website.. SSL makes it https :) try yourself accessing facebook with http, it comes to https :).. So I think I have answered your answer correctly now :)

Comment: The application can be accessed with both http and https. I just want to add in a code to detect which. For example, `http://www.google.co.in/` and `https://www.google.co.in`. Both are possible.

Comment: Have u implemented SSL for your application?

Comment: Yes. All thats done. Take example of Google, as given above. Lets assume a similar setup. I just want to know if user accessed http://... or https://....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21650/discussion-between-darkhorse-and-prabhat)